# Why can I write data to firestore but can't read it?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For some reason, I was able to write data to Firestore, but when attempting to retrieve the data, the doc snapshots doesn't have any data. This is weird because the program has worked before but it is suddenly stopped working.

Code for reading data:

```
static FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String _teamNumber;
  DocumentReference _teamRef;
  static final CollectionReference _teamsRef =
      _db.collection("2022").doc('info').collection('teams');

  TeamService(this._teamNumber) {
    _teamRef = _teamsRef.doc(_teamNumber);
  }

 static Stream<List<Match>> streamMatches(String teamNumber) {
    CollectionReference ref = _db
        .collection("2022")
        .doc('info')
        .collection('teams')
        .doc(teamNumber)
        .collection('matches');
    return ref.snapshots().map(
        (list) => list.docs.map((doc) => Match.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList());
  }
```

Code for Writing data:

```
static FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  static final CollectionReference _teamsRef =
      _db.collection("2022").doc('info').collection('teams');

  static Future<void> setMatchData(
    Match match,
    String uid,
    String name,
  ) async {
    await _teamsRef
        .doc(match.teamNumber)
        .collection('matches')
        .doc(match.matchNumber)
        .set({...match.toJson(), 'name': name, 'userId': uid});
  }
```

Security Rules in Firestore:

```
match /2022/info/teams/{document=**} {
        allow read, write, create: if true;
    }
    
    // Allow public access to team statistics
    match /team-statistics/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if true;
    }
    
    // Allow public access to user collection for signup and logins
    match /users/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if true;
    }
    
    // Allow public access to teams collection for signup and logins
    match /2021/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if true;
    }
        
    match /test/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if true
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your entire rule sets? There could be some other rule which overrides the read to be false.

Comment: Sure! I don't think there is anything wrong with it tho..